# Colors messed up when converting an image sequence to video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm generating a video from a PNG sequence using ffmpeg but the resulting video has wrong colors compared to the source files. Getting the correct colors is important because we're using our video assets side-by-side with image assets and the colors must match perfectly (or at least, be as visually similar as possible so as not to be jarring).

Our PNG input files are in the sRGB color profile.

Here's the command we're running:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i bg_analyse_%05d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p output5.mp4
```

And here's a comparison of a source PNG (left) and the same frame in the video (right):

[image]

From what we've gathered, H.264 does not support sRGB as a built-in color profile so I suppose ffmpeg must perform some kind of color conversion. However, the default ffmpeg settings seem to get the conversion wrong.

How can I get ffmpeg to export a video with colors as close visually as our PNG source files in the native H.264 color profile? I've tried various flags to try and specify input color profiles and more but nothing produced the expected results yet.

I didn't see many mention color profiles when it comes to generating videos from PNG sequences using ffmpeg. Must be because most aren't too picky on the output colors or simply don't notice? When putting our source assets with the video output side-by-side in our app, however, the difference is clear.

I already tried playing the video file in multiple players to make sure it's not a display issue  (QuickTime Player X, Chrome, etc.). The video is exactly the same (lighter than the source PNGs) in all players.

---

#### Edit 1:

In the end, the image and video will be displayed in Electron (Chromium). If that changes anything to how the video should be generated.

---

#### Edit 2:

We have an AfterEffects project from which the files are exported. We couldn't find any way to have that output correct colors so we hoped that using ffmpeg with a sequence of PNGs (which AE exports correctly) would give us more control over the final colors. Open to ideas on how to manage colors properly in AE, too.

Comment: Read this. https://mux.com/blog/your-browser-and-my-browser-see-different-colors/

Comment: @szatmary Very interesting information, but I'm having trouble figuring out what I'd need to do in terms of ffmpeg flags in order to get the proper result with our sRGB input files versus the BT.601 test file you're using in your article. Any other insight?

Comment: @szatmary Excuse the thread hijack, but `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i nullsrc=s=320x240:r=25:d=1 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -crf 18 -color_range pc 601.mp4` will work on all OS.

Comment: Lame suggestion is to try APNG: `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i bg_analyse_%05d.png output.apng`. No colorspace conversion to deal with. I did not test in Electron/Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

> Getting the correct colors is important because we're using our video assets side-by-side with image assets and the colors must match perfectly.

Then, you're going to need a completely different method.  No lossy video compression is going to what what you want.

If this video is an animation of some kind, you'll have to find another way to recreate it.

You can also try hacking around the problem.  For example, maybe your overlay PNG graphics utilize alpha channel to blend from their colors to the video's colors.

Comment: Correction: The colors must be as close as possible, but I understand it possibly can't be a 100% perfect match. Surely there is a way to make the video display colors in a similar way as an image on the same monitor? Another thing: we have an AfterEffects project from which the files are exported. We couldn't find any way to have that output correct colors so we hoped that using ffmpeg with a sequence of PNGs (which AE exports correctly) would give us more control over the final colors. Open to ideas on how to manage colors properly in AE, too.

Comment: @Form What's in this video?  If this is just an animation from AfterEffects, why not just do the animation in-browser?  You'll save a lot of bandwidth, and it will look better.  I think GreenSock can or used to be able to import directly from AfterEffects projects in some cases:  https://greensock.com/  There are other similar tools.

Comment: The video is too complex to be easily reproducible with GreenSock or similar (it contains effects, etc.). Otherwise it would indeed have been an option. Plus animating on the web shifts the workload from content producers to the web development side of things, which is not an option for us right now (time constraints).

Comment: If you've already read and applied @szatmary's advice, and you're still unhappy with the color output, then there's not much else you can do.  You'll have to work within the constraints of lossy video.

Answer (score 0):

In vectorscope we can see that the left and the right do not have any difference in hue, only brightness. So it is likely not a yuv2rgb matrix problem. sRGB uses a higher approximate gamma than bt709 (2.2 vs 1.961) which may be the real reason. I can confirm on my macOS Ventura machine with ffmpeg6.0 static build that converting png to mp4 without any metadata would result in brighter colors, but after adding `-color_trc iec61966-2-1`(the technical name of sRGB transfer, see T-REC H.273) to the cmdline the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -start_number 1 -i inputfile.%04d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -vf "scale=in_color_matrix=bt709:out_color_matrix=bt709" \
        -frames:v 100 -c:v libx264 -preset slower \
        -color_range tv -colorspace bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc iec61966-2-1 \
       -movflags faststart outputfile.mp4
```

-color_trc iec61966-2-1 tells ffmpeg to make the gamma of the resulting file sRGB, so it will display correctly in a browser. the "-vf" flag makes sure that you treat the colorspace as rec709 rather than bt601.

See - https://academysoftwarefoundation.github.io/EncodingGuidelines/Quickstart.html for more info.